# Unset a variable variable

Tags: php, variables

How do you unset a variable variable representing an array element?

```
function remove($var) {
    unset($$var);
}

$x=array('a'=>1,'b'=>2);
remove('$x["a"]');
var_dump(isset($x['a']));
```

The code above doesn't unset the array element `x['a']`. I need that same remove() function to work with `$_GET['ijk']`.

Comment: If you are only concerned about `$_GET`, then unset it directly.

Comment: Why don’t you use `unset($x["a"])` directly?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `unset()` or the `(unset)` cast.

If you want to use a function to unset, something like this would be better.

```
function removeMemberByKey(&$array, $key) {
    unset($array[$key]);
}
```

[It works!](http://codepad.org/N6BxGKy5)

Answer (score 1):

You can try,

```
function remove(&$var,$key) {
    unset($var[$key]);
}

$x=array('a'=>1,'b'=>2);
remove($x,'a');
var_dump(isset($x['a']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable variables cannot be used with superglobals, so if you need it to work for `$_GET` as well, you need to look at using a different method.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This:

<?php 
    /* Unset All Declair PHP variable*/
    $PHP_Define_Vars = array_keys(get_defined_vars());  
    foreach($PHP_Define_Vars as $Blast) {
      // or may be reset them to empty string# ${"$var"} = "";
      unset(${"$Blast"}); 
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

`unset` is easier to type then `remove`

When using it with an array element, the array will still exist

You could rewrite your function to treat the parameter as a reference;

EDIT: updated to use alex's code

`function remove(&$array, $key){
unset($array[$key]);
}
remove($x,'a');`

Comment: From the manual: "If a variable that is PASSED BY REFERENCE is unset() inside of a function, only the local variable is destroyed. The variable in the calling environment will retain the same value as before unset() was called."